# array to excel in phpexcel

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to convert array to excel using phpexcel. So my array format is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Box Name
            [2] => X1
            [3] => X2
            [4] => Y1
            [5] => Y2
            [6] => Patiend_ID
            [7] => Age
            [8] => Gender
            [9] => X-Axis
            [10] => X-Value
            [11] => Y-Axis
            [12] => Y-Value
        )

    [1] => 
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => HM
            [1] => 3.3
            [2] => 6.6
            [3] => 7.9
            [4] => 10
            [5] => 22
            [6] => 63
            [7] => MALE
            [8] => Medication Adherence
            [9] => 6
            [10] => Caloric output
            [11] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => ML
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 3.3
            [3] => 4.0
            [4] => 7.9
            [5] => 27
            [6] => 56
            [7] => FEMALE
            [8] => Medication Adherence
            [9] => 0
            [10] => Caloric output
            [11] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => LH
            [1] => 6.6
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 4.0
            [5] => 33
            [6] => 58
            [7] => MALE
            [8] => Medication Adherence
            [9] => 8
            [10] => Caloric output
            [11] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => LL
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 3.3
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 4.0
            [5] => 48
            [6] => 62
            [7] => FEMALE
            [8] => Medication Adherence
            [9] => 1
            [10] => Caloric output
            [11] => 3
        )
)
```

the code i have tried is

```
<?php




    /**
     * PHPExcel
     *
     * Copyright (C) 2006 - 2014 PHPExcel
     *
     * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
     * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
     * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
     * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
     *
     * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
     * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
     * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
     * Lesser General Public License for more details.
     *
     * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
     * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
     * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
     *
     * @category   PHPExcel
     * @package    PHPExcel
     * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006 - 2014 PHPExcel (http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel)
     * @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.txt    LGPL
     * @version    1.8.0, 2014-03-02
     */

    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                                 ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                                 ->setCategory("Test result file");



    $data=$_POST['name'];


    //print_r($_POST['name']);

    // Add some data
    /*$data = array(
        array ('Name', 'Surname'),
        array('Schwarz', 'Oliver'),
        array('Test', 'Peter')
    ); */


    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data, null, 'A1');

    // Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
                ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    // Redirect output to a client?s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
    ?>
```

So it giving error like invalid argument supplied. What am doing wrong. I am sending array from javascript to php using ajax call. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can `$data` be an array? it will be a string. How are you sending data with ajax?

Comment: post request 

$.post( "test.php", { name:patient_array } ) .done(function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  console.log(data);
  });

Comment: I don't think you can post array like that. You can only pass strings. You can try `name: JSON.stringify(patient_array)` and use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) at PHP to get your array.

Comment: Yea i have looked into it. But found that jquery will automatically handle this conversion of array. Maybe again will give a try for this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($data)`?

Comment: the array i posted above

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `$data` is an array when PHP receives it? Looking at your code, it is most likely to be a string because of the way you're simply assigning it from $_POST and also from your subsequent question. If it is indeed an array, then I need to spend what will probably be several days of effort looking for a bug in PHPExcel, trying to replicate your problem, delaying the new release of the next version.